# SendMessage и PostMessage Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi

Отправляю другой программе данные после работы, отправляю строкой. Хотел бы понять почему `PostMessage` не работает в то время как `SendMessage` отправляет данные. Мне не нужно возвращать результат после отправки сообщений, поэтому я хочу отказать от `SendMessage`.

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;
 
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure SendData(const copyDataStruct: TCopyDataStruct);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData); message WM_COPYDATA;
  end;
 
var
  Form2: TForm2;
 
implementation
 
{$R *.dfm}
 
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  stringToSend: string;
  copyDataStruct: TCopyDataStruct;
begin
  stringToSend := 'Avtorize sucefull';
 
  copyDataStruct.dwData := 0; // идентифицировать данные
  copyDataStruct.cbData := 1 + Length(stringToSend);
  copyDataStruct.lpData := PChar(stringToSend);
 
  SendData(copyDataStruct);
end;
 
procedure TForm2.SendData(const copyDataStruct: TCopyDataStruct);
var
  receiverHandle: THandle;
  res: integer;
begin
  receiverHandle := FindWindow(PChar('TForm2'), PChar('Form2'));
  if receiverHandle = 0 then
  begin
    form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(receiverHandle) + ' No');
    Exit;
  end;
 
 // res := SendMessage(receiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA, Integer(Handle), Integer(@copyDataStruct));
  PostMessage(receiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA, Integer(Handle), Integer(@copyDataStruct));
  form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(receiverHandle));
end;
 
procedure TForm2.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  s: string;
begin
 form2.Memo1.Lines.Add('sd');
  s := PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
  form2.Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  Msg.Result := 2006;      //Отошлем что-нибудь назад
end;
 
end.
```

Comment: Насколько помню, эти две функции делают одно и тоже, только одна дожидается пока обработается ее сообщение, а другая нет

Comment: Не в тему вопроса, но замечание по коду: Не стоит приводить указатели к Integer при передаче их в SendMessage, если не хотите проблем при сборке под win64. Используйте приведение к WPARAM и LPARAM https://stackoverflow.com/a/41967482

Comment: И ещё поправьте  `(1 + Length(stringToSend)) * SizeOf(Char);`

Comment: Есть недокументированное внутренне `WM_COPYGLOBALDATA`, которое для `PostMessage`. Но вообще лучше посмотреть в сторону других IPC. Пайпы, например.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `PostMessage` не может отправлять сообщения типа `WM_COPYDATA`.

Вот тут длинный пост, с объяснением:

[Why can't I PostMessage the WM_COPYDATA message, but I can SendMessageTimeout it with a tiny timeout?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110916-00/?p=9623)

Если в двух словах, то это связано с тем, что системе надо знать в какой момент сообщение доставлено и уже можно освободить внутренние буферы. Очевидно, что это можно сделать только используя синхронный вызов `SendMessage`.

Comment: Спасибо вам! Прочитал, понял. Появилась идея использовать низкий таймаут. Я еще не пробовал запустить эти процедуры в многопоточном приложении, но как мне кажется будут лишние паузы. Или передавать нажатие клавиши. Спасибо за замечание к коду.